# database design for dictionary of words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, dictionary

(my reason for asking this question is based on having read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758735/database-design-for-dictionary-application), which made me rethink my current setup)

I currently am developing a ruby on rails application in which there are many languages, each of which has a dictionary of base words attached to it, as well as a list of the words that map to each base word. The way I currently have it set up, there is a `base_words` table that contains the `base_word` as a string, along with the `language_id` as a foreign key. There is also a `words` table, each row of which contains a `word` string, along with the `base_word_id` as a foreign key. There is also a `language_id` indexed on each column, although I'm almost positive that this is superfluous due to the language_id on base_word, so I'm planning to take it off (although this could be a bad assumption on my part).

In sum, on the contrary to the answer I mentioned in the beginning, the tables are not separated by language, because I've reasoned that I can simply pull out the language words programmatically when the time comes. However, my application will also have translation(s) associated with each base word (as did the answer I referenced), and so I'm doubting my structure due to the realization that each translation will actually be a base_word in the same table as itself, which would mean that the translation would actually be just an id of another base word in said table. This may be completely fine, or it may not be - I have no clue (this is my first ever programming project).

Is this ok? Do I need to separate my base_words into separate tables for each language, or can I leave it all in one table?

Another example: I also need to store many phrases for each language, along with their translations. Should I have one table where each row has the appropriate translation of the phrase, or one table where each row contains simply one phrase and a language_id, or multiple tables (one for each language)?

Un saludo,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the other scenario, you'll have a `translations` table. There is no technical reason it couldn't have multiple foreign keys to `base_words` (a `source_word_id` and `target_word_id`, perhaps). So yes, you can absolutely store all your words in one table. There are some minor side effects involved with translations being directional relationships: it becomes possible to have translations which only work one way, and there will be many pairs of entries with opposite source and target. Neither of these is much of a worry: the first is even potentially desirable in order to represent words with double meanings in one language but not the other, and as for the second, space is cheap and indexing is easy.

You are correct that you do not need `words.language_id`, so long as you always join `base_words` when you're querying `words` and the language matters. This obviously changes if you have a use case where it makes sense to leave `base_words` out, but that scenario sounds unlikely based on what you describe.

As for phrases: why should they be handled any differently than base_words?

Comment: Thought provoking, on many levels. Great answer. In regards to why phrases should be handled differently: I'm not 100% sure of this answer, but I would say because of the same reason that words are handled differently than base words: they are shown at different times, for different reasons in the application, and stored with different information. Not to mention that a phrase is made up of many words (as opposed to base words). However, your logic is good - it's the same logic that almost led me to store words and base words in the same table with an is_base_word boolean.

Comment: Question: when would a translation ever only work one way...? Almost by the very definition of a translation, that doesn't make sense - if it works one way, it definitely works the other way in this specific instance. Maybe not for every scenario of that word, but for the specific scenario in which the translation was made, it should work - unless i'm deceiving myself