# Database design for complex dictionary

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dictionary, database-design

### INTRODUCTION

I need to design database for multi language dictionary.

I looked at [similar problem in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4758735/3137047), but it turned out to be a simpler case, not really applicable.

### Requirements

1. synonyms in every language
2. words with different ending but same root in the every language
3. multiple languages

### EXAMPLE

My thinking is resulted in something like this:

```
table: languages (id, name)
1, English
2, French

table: words (id, lang_id, word)
1, 1, cat
2, 1, pussy cat
3, 1, kitten
4, 1, puss
5, 2, le chat
6, 2, le felin

table: synonyms (id, word_id, word_id)
1, 1, 2
2, 1, 3
3, 1, 4
4, 5, 6

table: translations (id, word_id, word_id)
1, 1, 5
2, 2, 5
3, 3, 5
4, 4, 5
5, 1, 6
6, 2, 6
7, 3, 6
8, 4, 6
```

Yet here I see some problems:

- In order to access synonyms for word: `kitten`. One would need firstly find "master" word (`cat`) and then all synonyms of that word.
- The alternative is even worse, in my opinion, namely - storing all synonym relations for every word, which is redundant and can, "get out of control" fast...

### QUESTION 1

Am I missing something? Is there better way of organizing database in this case? Please share your take on this problem.

### QUESTION 2

At the moment, I do not know how to handle point 2 of requirements.

### FINALLY

Thank You for your time and knowledge.

Comment: I think you need something like "base word". It would be good for requriment 1 and first problem you have noticed.

Question 2: why not - SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'cat%';

Comment: Maybe look in to the Princeton Wordnet project. It is an ontology and covers only english, but may get you started

Comment: @RadosławHalicki Thank you for your ideas. I also thought about some sort of base word, though I did not know how to incorporate it in current design. I think that Rick James suggestion is the way forward. About second suggestion - it may be difficult to know how much characters to remove from ending as in different languages different rules apply. I do not know if it would be a good idea to incorporate every languages rules for word endings - it might be an overkill.

Comment: Hello. I saw accepted answer. I got the idea that the synonyms could be stored (word_id, word_id) (1,2),(2,3),(3,4) like a chain (linked list) - then one could search for synonyms by following a chain.

Comment: Hi @Rikijs what was your final solution? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's approach it differently.  Your example shows 6 words for "cat" (including "cat").  Let's call that `concept` number 1.

```
CREATE TABLE Concepts (
    concept MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    description TEXT  -- such as "feline animal"
);
```

Then the words are:

```
CREATE TABLE Words (
    word_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    concept MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    lang TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    word VARCHAR(111),
    INDEX(concept, lang, word),
    INDEX(lang, word)
);
```

That covers synonyms and translations.

Comment: Thank You - it seems like "the way to go".

Comment: The problem that I see now is how to come up with suitable descriptions for concepts "on the fly" as I have to read the words from excel document.

Comment: Well, that is a non-trivial linguistic problem.  There might be some PhD theses on the topic.  Good luck.

Comment: On the other hand, Google may be nearing a solution from a "bigdata" approach.