# design database for dictionary application

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, data-modeling

I'm trying to make a dictionary application but having a hard time designing my sql database (I'm very new to databases).
Here's the problem:
I want to store entries, entires can be words or sentences.
An entry can have one or more definitions.
If I made an entry for a word `foo` for example like so:

```
entry : Foo
Definitions: Foo means foobar bar
```

then later I made an entry for `Bar` like so:

```
entry : Bar
Definition: Bar means lorem
```

I want someway to connect all previous definitons that had the entry `Bar`, in this case Foo, so in my frontend I can put a link to `Bar's` definition in `Foo's` definiton. In other words after inserting `Bar` into the database When I get Foo's definitons from the database I want to also retrieve Bar's Id for example.
also entries can consist of more than one word. but the behaviour will still be the same.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758735/database-design-for-dictionary-application

Comment: @nbk I don't know if this translates into my problem.

Comment: try the accepted answer, adapt it to your needs, with the experience you can improve it#

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do such a thing would be to:

1. Each time you insert new entry, you check every entry to see which of them have this word. You can either do it with WHERE CONTAINS predicate, if your database supports it, or just manually search through every entry.
2. Add a marker around the word. For example, you are adding bar into dictionary and found an entry in foo, you update its definition to "Foo means foobar bar" (I used HTML because you mentioned links, but you can use whatever is suitable for you)

Then when you trying to find an entry you would parse the definition and add links looking through the database for needed entries.

Comment: I don't know anything about query optimization, but wouldn't this be slow?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it would be slow, but you can't know what entries does the sentence has without searching whole database. 

Another way (how most of dictionary/wiki websites do it) is to insert entry markers manually when you add the definition.